# Modal content "pages" and going back to previous page from button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, modal-dialog

I am doing this small website, not an app, that looks like an app.
It has modals. In the modal, you click on the links that take you further to the next view.
Then you can go back to the previous "page" or view from the back button on the modal's header and you can also close the modal.

How can I do the following:

1. Go back button goes to the previous view. If it's the first view, then it closes the modal.
2. Exit button closes the modal.
3. Modal content changes when clicking on the Next button. Or if there's no Next, then clicking on another button or link.

Here is the basic HTML code I've created:

```css
.modal{
  max-width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#f5f5f5;
  border-radius:6px;
}
.modal-header{
  position:relative;
  padding:20px;
  background:#eee;
  display:flex;
  text-align:center;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  border-radius:6px 6px 0 0;
}
.modal-header a{
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:#aaa;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
}
.close-modal{
  margin-left:auto;
}
.modal-header h3{
  margin:0 0 0 auto;
}
.modal-content{
  padding:30px;
}
.modal-content h2{
  text-align:center;
}
.modal-content .form-block{
  margin:20px 0;
}
.modal-content .form-control{
  width:100%;
  border:0;
  background:transparent;
  border-bottom:2px solid #aaa;
  padding:5px 0;
  height:40px;
}
.modal-content .btn{
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  background:blue;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:6px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a href="#" class="goback">&lt;</a>
    <h3>Title here</h3>
    <a href="#" class="close-modal">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h2>This is content 1st block</h2>
    <form>
      <div class="form-block">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write here" id="field-1" name="field-1" required>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="btn" id="myButton">Next</a>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h2>This is content 2nd block</h2>
    <form>
      <div class="form-block">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write here" id="field-2" name="field-2" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-block">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write here" id="field-3" name="field-3" required>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="btn" id="myButton">Next</a>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand that these "modal-content" blocks should have some IDs or something. Or those data-link tags. But, the goback link should be then updated with the correct link, right. I also would like to change "pages" with a transition effects. Like in apps when the next page flies in from right.

Comment: I answered ur question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this, tell me if its what you expected ?

All my code is commented.

```js
$(function(){
   // hide all elements exept first one
   $('.modal-content:not(:first)').hide();
   
   // add class last and first to last and fist modal-content divs
   $('.modal-content:first').addClass('first');   
   $('.modal-content:last').addClass('last'); 
   
   // click on go back
   $('.goback').click(function() {
      // check if its not the first div modal-content
      if (!$('.modal-content:visible').is('.first')) {
        var currentModalContent = $('.modal-content:visible');
        var prevModalContent = $(currentModalContent).prev('.modal-content');
        $(currentModalContent).hide();
        $(prevModalContent).fadeIn();       
      } else {
        // its the first div so we trigger the click to close the modal
        $('.close-modal').trigger('click');
      }
   });
   
   // close the modal
   $('.close-modal').click(function() {
      $('.modal').fadeOut();
   });  
   
   // click on go next 
   $('.btn').click(function() {
      // check if its not the last div modal-content 
      if (!$('.modal-content:visible').is('.last')) {
        var currentModalContent = $(this).parents('.modal-content');
        $(currentModalContent).hide();
        $(currentModalContent).next('.modal-content').fadeIn();
      } else {
        // its the last div 
        $(this).text('Another button');
      }
   });
});
```

```css
.modal{
  max-width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#f5f5f5;
  border-radius:6px;
}
.modal-header{
  position:relative;
  padding:20px;
  background:#eee;
  display:flex;
  text-align:center;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  border-radius:6px 6px 0 0;
}
.modal-header a{
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:#aaa;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
}
.close-modal{
  margin-left:auto;
}
.modal-header h3{
  margin:0 0 0 auto;
}
.modal-content{
  padding:30px;
}
.modal-content h2{
  text-align:center;
}
.modal-content .form-block{
  margin:20px 0;
}
.modal-content .form-control{
  width:100%;
  border:0;
  background:transparent;
  border-bottom:2px solid #aaa;
  padding:5px 0;
  height:40px;
}
.modal-content .btn{
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  background:blue;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:6px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a href="#" class="goback">&lt;</a>
    <h3>Title here</h3>
    <a href="#" class="close-modal">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h2>This is content 1st block</h2>
    <form>
      <div class="form-block">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write here" id="field-1" name="field-1" required>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="btn">Next</a>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h2>This is content 2nd block</h2>
    <form>
      <div class="form-block">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write here" id="field-2" name="field-2" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-block">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write here" id="field-3" name="field-3" required>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="btn">Next</a>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's a good solution! I had this done at the moment: https://codepen.io/R15T0/pen/LYZBryX

Comment: Your welcome, can you validate my answer and give me a upvote please ? Thank you :)

Comment: "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." - I am not sure if the vote worked.